# loop over array of numbers using for...in shows unexpected results

Tags: javascript

I have a js script.

I want to alert each number in an array.

But it always shows from 0 instead of the actual number.

```
var indexes = [1,2]
arrayOfDigits = indexes.map(Number);
var i = 0;
for (i in arrayOfDigits)
 {
                alert(i);
 }
```

It alerts 0 then 1.
But I want 1 then 2

Comment: `for ... in` iterates through the indexes of an array, not the values ... use `for ... of`

Answer (score 2):

Quite a number of issues with your code, let's go through them:

1. `for...in` is meant to be used to iterate over own, enumerable properties of objects, not for iterating over array members. You need `for...of` for this instead.
2. Don't use `var` any more unless you explicitly know and need its special scoping behaviour. Use `const` instead, or `let` in case you need to assign to it more than once.
3. Your code has an undeclared variable which automatically makes it a global variable. It is common consensus to not pollute the global namespace. Always declare any variables before use.
4. Don't initialize or even declare the loop variable of a `for...of` loop outside of the loop. This is done right in the `for (const digit of arrayOfDigits)` construct itself.
5. Don't use `alert` for debugging; use `console.log` instead.

Here's the working, corrected code:

```js
const indexes = [1, 2]
const arrayOfDigits = indexes.map(Number);

for (const digit of arrayOfDigits) {
  console.log(digit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for-in loop loops over all the property of an object (including those from its prototype chain). All you want is to iterate over it. For that you can use a for-of loop (which loops over elements), or you could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which does just that but can help you have access to other stuff like the index:

```
indexes.forEach(number => {
    alert(number);
 });
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; your code produces the output the OP says they desire.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks. Sometimes simplicity is not good enough I guess!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are keen to have output as 1 and 2 use this instaed,

```js
var indexes = [1,2]
    arrayOfDigits = indexes.map(Number);
    for (var i = 0;i<arrayOfDigits.length;i++)
     {
                    alert(arrayOfDigits[i]);
     }
```